# SceneKit's node.childNode(withname: recursively:) finds node on iOS 11 but not 9 or 10

Tags: ios, scenekit

I have a fairly simple SceneKit `.scn` comprising a couple of lights and a couple of cameras and a reference node that comes from a `.dae` file in the same `.scnassets` bundle.

On iOS 11 (real or simulator), the scene loads correctly. On 9 (real, I don't have a simulator of that version) or 10 (real or simulator) `scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "MyNodeName", recursively: true)` returns nil.

Loading the `.dae` that provides the node "MyNodeName" as a scene in it's own right succeeds, so it is being copied as part of the asset bundle.

I know that some SceneKit functionality is a recent addition but according to the docs this method has been around since iOS 8. The `Load Policy` of the reference node is set to `Immediately` (in Interface Builder's node inspector).

What could explain this behaviour?

**Edited to add:**

It seems iOS 9 and 10 don't automatically load reference nodes, despite the Load Policy setting in Interface Builder:

At the moment of attempting to find the child node, on iOS 10:

```
(lldb) p scene.rootNode.childNodes.map { $0.name }
([String?]) $R1 = 3 values {
  [0] = “Reference node”
  [1] = "Cameras"
  [2] = "Lights"
}
(lldb) p scene.rootNode.childNodes[0].childNodes.map { $0.name }
([String?]) $R2 = 0 values {}
(lldb)
```

The same moment, on iOS 11:

```
(lldb) p scene.rootNode.childNodes.map { $0.name }
([String?]) $R11 = 3 values {
  [0] = “Reference node”
  [1] = "Cameras"
  [2] = "Lights"
}
(lldb) p scene.rootNode.childNodes[0].childNodes.map { $0.name }
([String?]) $R10 = 1 value {
  [0] = “Actual node“
}
```

Is there a way to force a Scene to load it's reference nodes? I can find nothing in the docs, for either the scene or the root node. If not, reference nodes in a scene don't seem to be very useful for iOS < 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that while replacing/updating the `.dae` was no problem for the SceneKit editor or iOS 11 (simulated or real), iOS 9 and 10 were both confused by something subtle in the way the node was referenced, causing them to fail to find it.

Removing and re-creating the reference node in the main scene was the solution.